# #JavaScript - Por qué me sale error de objeto "no iterable"?

Tags: javascript, json, objeto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resulta que estoy tratando de mostrar unos objetos de un JSON en un innerHTML, pero al hacer el for y recorrer los array, me sale que la variable no es iterable. Qué podría hacer? Es un toplist. Gracias.

```
function cargarDatos() {
const peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
// peticion.open('GET', 'datos.json');
peticion.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/datos.json', true);

peticion.send();

peticion.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
        /* console.log(this.responseText);  */
        let datos = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        
        console.log(datos); 

        for (let item of datos) {
            console.log(item);
            
        }
        
    }
}  };
```

Comment: Con un fetch te puedes ahorrar toda la parefernalia que implica el httprequest. Si te sirve de algo.

Comment: Si, vi también esa opción, pero me tocaba hacerlo con httprequest, muchas gracias de todas formas!!

Answer (score 0):

Porque no estas iterando el array en sí. Sería así:

```
for (let item of datos.canciones){
  console.log(item)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!.